# Clojure macro to allow writing code without let bindings

Tags: clojure, macros

I am trying to write a macro that will allow me to do the following

```
(without-nesting
  (:= x 1)
  (:= y 2)
  (:= z 3)
  (db-call x y z)
  (:= p 33)
  (db-call x y z p))
```

becomes

```
(let [x 1 
      y 2 
      z 3]
  (db-call x y z)
  (let [p 33]
    (db-call x y z p)))
```

So far my implementation has been the following

```
(defn assignment?
  [[s _]]
  (= s ':=))

(defmacro without-nesting
  [& body]
  (let [[bindings xs] (split-with assignment? body)
        [non-bindings remaining] (split-with (complement assignment?) xs)]
    `(let [~@(mapcat rest bindings)]
       ~@non-bindings
       ~(when (seq remaining)
          `(without-nesting ~@remaining)))))
```

I'm having issues when `remaining` is going to be empty. In my current implementation a `nil` gets placed which prevents the last form in `non-bindings` to return its value. I have no clue on how to proceed with a recursive macro. Can someone help

**UPDATE:**

So I was able to get rid of the nil but I just want to know if there's a better way to deal with this

```
(defmacro without-nesting
  [& body]
  (let [[bindings xs] (split-with assignment? body)
        [non-bindings remaining] (split-with (complement assignment?) xs)]
    `(let [~@(mapcat rest bindings)]
       ~@non-bindings
       ~@(if (seq remaining)
           [`(without-nesting ~@remaining)]
           []))))
```

Also would this be a good way to write code? Or do you see any caveats? For me it looks more linear as compared to nested `let`

I do see how ppl may abuse this. In the case of `let`, if the nesting becomes too much, then it's a hint to refactor the code. This might hide that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `let`. It is already recursive. To incorporate function calls where you only care about the side effects, the convention is to bind to an underscore.

```
(let [x 1 
      y 2 
      z 3
      _ (db-call x y z)
      p 33
      _ (db-call x y z p)])
```